# "The application was requested to shut down with a ShutdownRequested call" message in ReSharper Ultimate options

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

After installing Visual Studio 2015 and Resharper Ultimate I'm getting this error:

> "The application was requested to shut down with a ShutdownRequested
>   call"

[image: The application was requested to shut down with a ShutdownRequested call]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to properly accept the "JetBrains Privacy Policy" popup.

If you do not see it, it is hidden by other UI elements, so resize the popup to get the bottom part of the popup where buttons exist.

[image: JetBrains Privacy Policy]